# Excel - Retrieve value in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing

In my organisation, there are a couple of excel functions that return large array like more than 2000 rows and several columns.

Dummy Code / Dummy Example :

```
{=FunctionThatReturnArray(param1)}
```

where param1 is the date

[image: Screenshot]

I need to retrieve the selling price for the combination « Shoes » « Yellow » for different dates.

I don’t want to display an entire array, for every date I’m interested in.

Instead, I would like to display only the value that I need.

I tried to used the Index function as below, but as the combination Shoes/Yellow isn’t always at the fifth row, it doesn’t work.

```
{=INDEX(FunctionThatReturnArray(param1),5,4)}
```

where 5 is the RowNumber and 4 the ColNumber

I believe I need to use the Match Function somehow, but on the 2 different column.

How could I do that without displaying the entire array on my worksheet ?

Thanks in advance and kind regards
Largo

Comment: I am not sure if this will work with "virtual" arrays. But have you tried using `=SumIfs()` which works very well in this case when the array / table is actually materialized on the sheet.

Comment: Processing arrays is quick - why not just loop through the whole thing?

Comment: I'm not quite clear - would the combination shoes/yellow appear on multiple dates and if so what should happen?

Comment: I've realised that the date is a parameter to your function, so looks as if you just want a single value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you want, but you are right, you would have to match on both the 2nd and 3rd columns then index into the 4th column like this:

```
=INDEX({43466,"Pants","Yellow",40;43466,"Shirt","Green",20;43466,"Shoes","Blue",70;43466,"Shoes","Yellow",75},MATCH(1,
(INDEX({43466,"Pants","Yellow",40;43466,"Shirt","Green",20;43466,"Shoes","Blue",70;43466,"Shoes","Yellow",75},0,2)=B2)*
(INDEX({43466,"Pants","Yellow",40;43466,"Shirt","Green",20;43466,"Shoes","Blue",70;43466,"Shoes","Yellow",75},0,3)=C2),0),4)
```

Where I have used an array constant to test it, you would need multiple references to your Array Function to achieve this.

[image]

BTW the 43466 is the number representation of 1/1/2019.

Comment: Hi Tom, You're the man. Thanks very much it solved my problem. Kind regards